# How do you revert a rendered math equation back into it's text code?

Tags: microsoft-word, equation-editor

I discovered `\eqarray` in Word's equation editor. I think it's very useful, but I would like to know how to edit my input after I've rendered it without having to retype the whole thing again.

*Example:*
If I were to type in Word's equation editor mode:

```
\eqarray(2&x+&3&y=5@&x+&&y=7)
```

It would render:
[rendered out put from \eqarray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai2Rf.png)

If I wanted to change a coefficient of one of the x's (for example), is there a way to do this without retyping the whole equation?

*Note: Please forgive the link to the rendered out rather than an embedded image. I don't have enough points to make a post with an embedded image yet.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your mind right after entering the equation, the keyboard shortcut of Ctrl + Z will take you back to the formula entry box with the equation as you originally typed it ... then you can make your revisions.

If you are beyond the practical Undo functionality, clicking on the equation and using the pulldown menu arrow, select Linear and edit the formula as needed. When done, place your cursor insertion point at the end of the revised formula and click return.